# i have one web site which was static and now i have moved it on dynamic and my all pages url have high page rank so what should i do?

Tags: url, dynamic, static

i have one web site which was static and now i have moved it on dynamic and my all pages url have high page rank so what should i do ?

Comment: high page rank is good. you don't like that?

Comment: @Anurag -- I think the problem is that the **old** urls had high page rank, not the new ones.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Redirect directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) or [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to redirect visitors (and the Google crawler) from your old pages to your equivalent new one.  Most shared hosting providers allow you to do this sort of thing in an .htaccess file (assuming you're on Apache).  [Here's a nice tutorial on URL rewriting](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html) which may help.  Here's an article on [using redirects to preserve pagerank](http://www.seocompany.ca/seo/url-redirect.html).

Answer (score 1):

Redirect your old urls to the appropriate new ones.  Consider setting up and submitting a [sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) to Google.  Check out Google's [Webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) for more idea.